# why do site redirects appear in Google results?

Tags: http, http-status-codes, redirect

Inishturkbeg.com query.

If you search "inisturkbeag" (which should people
apparently do), you get inisturkbeag.org, which redirects to
inishturkbeg.com. Is there any way we can remove these from Google?
Is it an ISP thing?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're doing a [302 Temporary Redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302), instead of a [301 Permanent Redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301).

You may be interested in checking out the following article to see how Google handles 302 Redirects:

- [Matt Cutts: SEO advice: Discussing 302 redirects](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-advice-discussing-302-redirects/)

In addition, quoting the [Google Webmaster Central](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633):

> If you need to change the URL of a page as it is shown in search engine results, we recommended that you use a server-side 301 redirect. This is the best way to ensure that users and search engines are directed to the correct page. The 301 status code means that a page has permanently moved to a new location.